# How do I successfully insert information from a form into a database using a prepared statement with mysqli and php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently working on a Examination Management System that's supposed to generate examination papers, extracting them from a bank of questions. I have been working on the inserting questions function for quite some time now (couple of days to be honest) with no success what so ever.

The insert function I am using includes a prepare statement, worked successfully when I applied it on a simple project I got from the internet. The database updated perfectly. But when applying the same concept in my own project, nothing seemed to happen.

I'm sure its nothing to do with the SQL queries, because no SQL error popped up. I checked the db connections, syntax, SQL queries, and compared it side by side with the working project, all looks fine. I'm new to Php, and would enormously appreciate any assistance to help figure this out. Thanks in advance!

I'm using Php 7.0.2 and Mysqli 2.4. Also I'm using bootstrap for html.

Here is the code for dbconnect.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","register");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Code of insert.php page:

```
<?php
require('dbconnect.php');
include("auth.php");

$status = "";
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1){

    $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $question = $_REQUEST['question'];
    $answer1 = $_REQUEST['answer1'];
    $answer2 = $_REQUEST['answer2'];
    $answer3 = $_REQUEST['answer3'];
    $answer4 = $_REQUEST['answer4'];
    $submittedby = $_SESSION["username"];


$ins_query = "INSERT INTO mcquestions (`quest_desc`, `answ1`, `answ2`, `answ3`, `answ4`, `trn_date`, `submittedby`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"; 

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $ins_query)) {
    echo "SQL Error";
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $question, $answer1, $answer2, $answer3, $answer4, $trn_date, 
        $submittedby);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
    $status = "New Record Inserted Successfully. </br></br><a href='view.php'>View Inserted Record</a>";
}
?>
```

Here is the Html form for inserting questions:

```
</head>
<div id="page-wrapper"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Questions</h1>
            </div>
           <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
      <!--   /.row --> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Basic Form Elements
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                              <form method="POST" action="insert.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />                               
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Text area</label>
                                        <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" rows="3" name="question" placeholder="Enter Question" required> </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Answer" name="answer1"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Second Answer" name="answer2"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Third Answer" name="answer3"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Fourth Answer" name="answer4"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div><p style="color:#FF0000;"><?php //echo $status; ?></p></div>                                      
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When you're using a prepared statement, you shouldn't escape the input. Do you get any PHP errors, or errors from `mysqli_error($con)` / `mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)`?

Comment: I tried that, at first wasn't using the escape function, only recently added them to see if it would give anything. Not at all, no errors popped up. The page just refreshed and the form went empty. But database still empty.

Comment: Your `<input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" /> ` is outside the form though, so it won't be sent. Therefor, the check to see if the form was submitted will always fail.

Comment: Okay. Now I pasted it within the form. Nothing really changed though. And to be extra sure, I tried using a simple html form without the bootstrap and all to see if it has something to do with the form, and same results too.

Comment: You also don't have an `action` or `method` attribute to target the insert-page or to say you're sending over POST. `<form role="form">` should be `<form role="form" method="POST" action="insert.pnp">` - `role` isn't a valid HTML5 attribute either.

Comment: Okay, added action and method attribute into the form tag. Tried again but db still nothing. So role="form" isn't required?

Comment: @MujahidSac it isn't required. `<input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" /> ` field should be in `<form>`. if you have already changed then edit your question. else other user point out this again.

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani Okay, I edited the question. To this point, I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the functions in php

Comment: Found out that it was something to do with the database. I deleted and created a new one manually it works like a charm! Thanks for the time spent in assisting me.

Answer (score 0):

firstly I don't get `</head>` in your html.
2nd thing you are not starting session in your insert.php. start it in top of the code.

```
session_start();
```

and make sure your are initializing your session variable like `$_SESSION["username"]='user1'`. 
if it still didn't work then make sure you are connecting to right/correct db.